# CSS3 Keyframe Animated opacity break z-index order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code in a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hhn6r3zn/

Basically I'm animating a div using CSS3 keyframes and I want the Image to be above it- but even when using z-index it is not working.

[image: The wrapper is correctly behind the image, but the animated div is not]

However when I stop changing the opacity it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/ax1566b0/

[image: Opacity at 1 the image is working]

Code:

```css
.pulse {
    width: 32px;
    background: #1A4886;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes twinkly {
    0% {opacity: 1; width:0px;margin-left:14px; height:0px;z-index:0;}
 
    100% {opacity: 0;z-index:0;}

}

.pulse {
    animation: twinkly 2s infinite;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: -14px;
 z-index: 0;
}

.switch{
 width:50px;
 height:75px;
}

.pulse-wrapper{
 z-index:0;
    background:red;
}
.button-wrapper{
z-index:1;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
       <div class="button-wrapper"><a type="button" class="btn"><img src="http://toptix.com/wp-content/plugins/codecanyon-5586825-image-map-hotspot-wordpress-plugin-v1.2.5/img/icon1.png" /></a></div>
       <div class="pulse-wrapper"><div class="pulse"></div></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the opacity to animate whilst keeping it behind the image?

Comment: Remember to use `z-index` you need to specify a position.

Comment: That was it, thanks @user1672694

Comment: glad I could help. I've posted my comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `z-index` property to be applied the element's position must be set to something other than the initial `static`
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/